# Algebra I: Cyclic Generators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

The direct product $\mathbb{Z}_{45} \times \mathbb{Z}_{98}$ is cyclic and isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{4410}$ because $gcd(45,98)=1$; furthermore the element $n=([1]_{45},[1]_{98})$ is a cyclic generator. Find the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $mn=([29]_{45},[17]_{98})$

Comment: Can you tell us what is confusing you?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Chinese remainder theorem

Answer (score 0):

You need $m$ such that $m\equiv 29 \mod{45}$ and $m\equiv 17 \mod{98}$.

You have that $m=29+45x$ from the first one and then from the second one you get:
$$
29+45x-17\equiv 0 \mod{98} \Rightarrow 12+45x=98y
$$
So you need to solve $12=-45x+98y$ or equivalently $45t+98s=1$ since $gcd(45,98)=1$. From Euclidean algorithm you obtain that $t=98k+61$, $s=-45k-28$ for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.
We need the smallest negative such $t$ so $x$ is the smallest positive that works.
For $k=-1$ we get:

$$
t=-37 \quad s=17
$$
So $x=37*12$ hence $m=29+45*37*12=20009$.

Comment: @Downvoter Please comment if I missed something in my answer or made some mistake.

Answer (score -1):

m=29mod45 and m=17mod98

so

29+45m=17mod98 and 45m=-12mod98=86mod98

m=52

Comment: The first one implies that $m=45k+29$.
Check that $m=52$ doesn't satisfy $m\equiv 29\mod{45}$.